# Mule 3.3 ignore-resource-not-found

Tags: spring, properties, mule

I'm using Mule Studio 1.3.2, which corresponds to Mule 3.3 I believe.

I'm using a property-placeholder element.  I wanted to use the technique described [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files) of having an optional override file.  However, the ignore-resource-not-found attribute is being flagged as an error in Mule Studio:  **Attribute ignore-resource-not-found is not defined as a valid property of property-placeholder**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

Is this broken or am I doing something silly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mule 3.3` uses [Spring context 3.1 schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd)

which supports `ignore-resource-not-found` attribute

```
<xsd:complexType name="propertyPlaceholder">
   <xsd:attribute name="location" type="xsd:string">...</xsd:attribute>
   <xsd:attribute name="properties-ref" type="xsd:string">...</xsd:attribute>
   <xsd:attribute name="file-encoding" type="xsd:string">...</xsd:attribute>
   <xsd:attribute name="order" type="xsd:integer">...</xsd:attribute>
   <xsd:attribute name="ignore-resource-not-found" type="xsd:boolean" default="false">
      <xsd:annotation>
         <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[Specifies if failure to find the property resource location should be ignored. Default is "false", meaning that if there is no file in the location specified an exception will be raised at runtime.]]>
         </xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
   </xsd:attribute>
   <xsd:attribute name="ignore-unresolvable" type="xsd:boolean" default="false">...         </xsd:attribute>
   <xsd:attribute name="local-override" type="xsd:boolean" default="false">...</xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

so, you're doing the right thing

Comment: Hmmm.  I can't upload pictures to StackOverflow because I don't have enough reputation points, but there's an image of it showing the problem here: http://i775.photobucket.com/albums/yy35/tdeffler/ignore_resource_zps73363fab.jpg

Comment: Mule Studio shows bug for lot of stuff but it runs fine. Try running it and should run fine

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize Mule Studio couldn't be relied upon.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under **Window -> Preferences -> Mule Studio -> Turn off error reporting in XML editor**

This may let through valid errors too, but in my case, I turned it on after verifying everything was working fine. Just kept annoying me, those "red markers".

Do not forget to turn it off, when you modify the flow though.